# Submit "Test notes" or "instructions WP8 app submission - Where can I find them?

Tags: authentication, submit, windows-phone, store

Short version:
Can't find the field "Test Notes" or "Instructions" where I can include log in credentials for the app I'm submitting. Where can I find the fields?

Long version:
My verification faild when I submitted a WP8 app, because I didn't include log in credentials so they could test the app. This simply because I didn't find any place to put them (don't want them to be public). So I got feedback from MS:

"Comments: The application cannot be tested for compliance for Windows Phone Application Certification Requirements due to geographic, hardware, and/or software limitation(s). Please provide valid test account credentials with resubmission."

But I just can't find where to put them! So I read the guidelines:

"If your app requires credentials, you must include them in the Test notes or instructions field when submitting your app on the Windows Phone Dev Center."

As I said, where can I find "Test notes" or "instructions"? Where are they?

Thanks!

// Tibbelit

Comment: The answer is found here:
Under the Upload and describe your XAP click on More Xap Options
// Tibbelit

Comment: Put that as your answer, then 'Accept' it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is found here: Under the Upload and describe your XAP click on More Xap Options.